# Performance of Sorting a HashMap by Value vs Using TreeMap or LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, performance, sorting, hashmap, treemap

I'm currently sorting a HashMap by value and was wondering whether performance would be better if  it was better to sort using something like a TreeMap instead.

I know that HashMap's have an insertion and sorting complexity of o(1) time and a tree sort in java will take log(n) (I believe), but I'm wondering what the cost of sorting a HashMap actually is.

I'm currently sorting with:

```
 public static HashMap sortByValue(Map unsortMap) {
    List list = new LinkedList(unsortMap.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue())
                    .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue());
        }
    });

    HashMap sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
    for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Which method would be best to use and why?

Edit: I meant searching, not sorting complexity.

Comment: What is the second way you have in mind? Why are you using raw types? Java 5 is out for more than 10 years. Use generic types.

Comment: what do you mean by `sorting complexity of o(1) time`? :o

Comment: There isn't a better way to do it.  "Sorting with a TreeMap" by value isn't really possible, and people who try to tell you it is are lying.

Comment: Measuring is knowing.

Comment: If your goal is performance, you can simply use a `System.currentTimeMillis()` to calculate the running time of some scenarios of two cases and see which is faster. Because the time of sorting normally depends of how big and shuffled is the collection.

Comment: There's no thing such as a *best* method. It all depends on your data, and on whether you want to optimize insertions vs traversing the map, i.e. is your app write-intensive or read-intensive? Etc etc etc.

Comment: @karthik Sorry, I meant inserting and searching, I'll update the question.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner "There's no thing such as a best method" I understand that, I should have explained my case a bit more. I'm getting the data, storing it in a HashMap and then immediately sorting it each time I get the data. Therefore I was trying to understand the complexity involved in sorting the HashMap and whether it would be a better idea to sort the data previously in some fashion such as using a data structure like a TreeMap.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is, is the performance of inserting into a sorted data structure such as a LinkedHashMap or TreeMap generally better than using a HashMap and sorting the HashMap by Value. 

Sorry for the poor question, I guess its been a long day.